# Laravel/ Angular- POST 500 (Internal Server Error) when generating PDF

Tags: php, angular, laravel, post, httpresponse

I have a Laravel/ Angular application, and on one of the pages, the user is given the option to be able to export data about a single/ selection of transactions to a PDF file.

The PDF generated currently displays 3 pages (the first one is for each of the actual transactions, and the subsequent pages display more information about the accounts those transactions belong to).

I want to add some functionality to this feature, so that if the transaction being exported only has a single deposit date against it, when its status is 'request', then only the first page of the PDF currently generated should actually be generated (the rest of the PDF that would normally be generated should be suppressed).

I have added an `if` statement to the blade.php file which displays the content of the PDF as follows:

```
@if(($transaction->count($transaction['transactionItem']) == 1) && ($transaction['transactionItem']['currentStatusId'] == '1010'))
    <body ... >
        // Content of first page of PDF here
    </body>
@else
    <body ... >
        // Original content of full PDF here
    </body>
@endif
```

In the HTML, the menu item with the link that calls the function to download the PDF is written with:

```
<td class="provActionsCell contactAddressCell text-center table__priority-column" id="reduceWidth-doublePlus" dropdown>
    <a href class="icon icon-kog" dropdownToggle></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="angular-simple-dropdown">
        ...
        <li *ngIf="payer.provStatusTag !== 'NA'" (click)="exportSingleTransactionToPDF(payer)"><a href="">Download PDF</a></li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

The `exportSingleTransactionToPDF()` function is written in provisional-reminders.ts with:

```
exportSingleTransactionToPDF(payer) {
    let requestData = (<any>Object).assign({});
    console.log("requestData: ", requestData);
    payer.loading = true;
    requestData['transactionItem'] = payer;
    console.log("requestData['transactionItem']: ", requestData['transactionItem']);

    this.provService.generateSingleTransactionPDF(requestData).subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
            payer.loading = false;
            this.showPrintDialog = false;
        },
        (error:any) => {
            const message = new Message();
            message.type = MessageType.ERROR;
            message.message = error.message || 'There was a problem generating the PDF.';
            this.messagingService.emitMessage(message);

            payer.loading = false;
        }
    );

    return false;
}
```

and the `generateSingleTransactionPDF()` function it calls is defined in `prov.service.ts` with:

```
generateSingleTransactionPDF(data: any): Observable<any> {
    const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.pdfHeaders, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob });
    console.log("requestOptions: ", requestOptions);
    console.log("data: ", data);

    return this.http
        .post(this.generateSingleTransactionPDFUrl, data, requestOptions)
        .map((res: Response) => {
            const blob = <Blob>res.blob();
            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, `provisional-tax-reminder.pdf`);
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Currently, when I try to download a PDF, I can see some of the debug I've added displayed in the console, showing that these functions are being called, and I then get an error banner in the browser that says:

> There was a problem generating the PDF

which is clearly coming from the `exportSingleTransactionToPDF()` function, as that is the only place in the project that this error message appears. This error is thrown when the call to `generateSingleTransactionPDF()` function call returns an error, so clearly, the `return` statement of `generateSingleTransactionPDF()` is returning an error somehow, but I'm not sure how/ why, or how I would debug what that error is, and what's causing it...?

The `generateSingleTransactionPDFUrl()` function called inside the `return` statement's `.post()`is defined at the start of the prov.service.ts file with:

```
private generateSingleTransactionPDFUrl: string = BASE_URL + '/web-api/t/prov/pdf';
```

There is an error displayed in the browser console, which says:

> POST http://... 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> unparsable response

This seems to suggest that the error is because the response of the HTTP request is unparsable, but I can't figure out why this would be the case... the `console.log()` statements I put inside the `generateSingleTransactionPDF()` function in prov.service.ts display the `requestOptions` & `data` variables in the console- and they appear to be holding the correct data... so I'm not sure why it's saying that the response is unparsable- anyone have any ideas?

**Edit**

So, having looked in the log file, it seems I have an error that says:

> Next ErrorException: Undefined variable: transaction (View: /.../reminder.blade.php) in /../views/419cdd3906d761bc1bb55581502a15d04c1fe7a7.php:9

which seems to be complaining about the `if` I've put at the start of my blade.php file:

```
@if(($transaction->count($transaction['transactionItem']) == 1) && ($transaction['transactionItem']['currentStatusId'] == '1010'))
```

How would/ should I access this `$transaction` variable from inside the blade.php file?

Comment: Check your error logs in `storage/logs`, it should give you more information why it failed. You may need to look at the PHP more than the angular code.

Comment: Thanks, I did originally have a look at the log file, but didn't spot anything. Had another look just now, following your comment, and seems I missed an error (it wasn't right at the end of the file, and was further up than I was expecting...)

Comment: Seems it was because of how I was referencing a PHP variable from inside the blade.php file... Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong there, and how I can correct it?

Comment: It looks like `$transaction` is not being defined. Make sure you're passing the correct variable into your view, or that it's being defined properly within your view.

Comment: Thanks. I seem to have resolved that- was able to access the `transactionItem` variable directly, rather than going through its parent `$transaction` variable... but now get an error in the log that says: `Next ErrorException: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else(T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF)...` The structure of my blade.php file is: `@if(...) <body></body> @else <body><body> @endif`... so I don't see what I'm doing wrong with that. Any thoughts?

Comment: You probably don't have something else closed that's throwing everything off. Use proper indentation, and if you can see the parsed view (usually in storage/views or something similar), it might give a hint.

Comment: Yeah, it is all indented correctly, and as far as I can tell, everything is closed properly (the HTML is all the same as it was before I added the `@if` statements in... In storage/app/views there are a number of files with random names, i.e. asdf987wertlihsvo78ywert.php etc... no idea which of these I'd look in...?

Comment: Sometimes you have to look for the most recent file, or just do a grep to search for something that exists in that view, such as `grep transaction *` to figure out which file it is. Once you have that, load it up into an editor with error checking, and you can hopefully find out what is causing the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow what you mean there? How would I `grep transaction *`?

Comment: The file mentioned in the error in the laravel.log file is the blade.php file that I've added the `@if`, `@else` & `@endif` to...

Comment: `grep` is a command-line search tool, for searching within files. Can you [edit] the post with the blade file?

Comment: Ah sorry, yeah, just realised what you meant. I've opened up the relevant file from storage/framework/views - not sure what I'm looking for in there though...?

Comment: The line that the error in the log file is complaining about is the blank line at the end of the file...

Comment: It's complaining because something is not closed, like a brace or a logic check. Load the file up in an editor with syntax checking, and you might be able to find it.

Comment: Yeah- I've got it open in an editor with syntax highlighting... I've just gone through, and manually checked every tag- they are all closed... Do I have the `@if`s in the right places? i.e. after the `<head></head>`, and then outside the `<body></body>`, but inside the `<html></html>`?

Comment: For what you've posted, that's correct. That doesn't mean that there isn't something else within the body tags that's throwing it off.